# How to Catch CannotGetJdbcConnectionException in Spring REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am working on creating some RESTful web services using `Spring` and `OAuth`. When the database is turned off, somewhere in the framework a `CannotGetJdbcConnectionException` - when I say somewhere in the framework, I mean that it is caused within the Spring code and not within code that I have written. The REST response I get back is:

```
{
"timestamp": 1467982842783
"status": 500
"error": "Internal Server Error"
"exception": "org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException"
"message": "Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect"
"path": "/1/test"
}
```

I have tried numerous things. For example, I have tried creating a class that extends `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`, like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(CannotGetJdbcConnectionException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleNoConnection() {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Unable to connect to the database. Is it running?", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

But the method `handleNoConnection` is never caught, indeed, no method in the base class (`ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`) is called - I have put breakpoints in each one.

I also tried creating a class that extends from `BasicErrorController` and it does break within there, but there is no Exception object (it only exists as a type name as a string). For example:

```
@Controller
public class ErrorController extends BasicErrorController {

    public ErrorController() {
        super(new DefaultErrorAttributes());
    }   

    @Override public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<String,Object>> error(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Map<String, Object> body = getErrorAttributes(request,
                isIncludeStackTrace(request, MediaType.ALL));
        HttpStatus status = getStatus(request);
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(body, status);
    };

    @RequestMapping(
            value = {"${error.path:/error}"},
            produces = {"text/html"}
    )
    public ModelAndView errorHtml(HttpServletRequest request) {


        final HttpStatus status = getStatus(request);
        if (status == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED) {
            return new ModelAndView("error401");
        } else if (status == HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN) {
            return new ModelAndView("error403");
        } else {
            return new ModelAndView("error500");
        }
    }

    public HttpStatus getStatus(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Integer statusCode = (Integer)request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
        if(statusCode != null) {
            try {
                return HttpStatus.valueOf(statusCode.intValue());
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    }
}
```

I am unsure of what else to do. As I said, I cannot catch the exception directly because it is happening within the Spring code itself. Is there any other way to catch this exception?

Comment: your "status": 500 accurse because of an internal server error does not explicitly mean that there is no connection. Server can return this error for example when it can not find the correct match what exact method to invoke. Check if your request mopping is correct

Comment: @v_haruty My question isn't concerning the 500 error. My question is a more generic how to catch an exception that occurs outside of my code - inside of the Spring framework. In this case, a CannotGetJdbcConnectionException exception is occurring and I would like to catch it.